# C++ Data Server and J2ME client communication

Tags: java, c++, sockets

I am working on a robot that has some AI built in. However, the mandated robot controller does not have the power to do the work onboard. This means that I need to use a co-processor.

I am writing all of my AI in C++. This will also be a TCP server. I have an idea for the protocol. The C++ server receives commands and only sends back values when absolutely required. The String for a basic command would be:

```
REQUEST DATA PUT data storename ENDREQ
```

The C++ server would parse the request and store data under the reference of storename.

To read data from the server:
The Java request would be:

```
REQUEST DATA GET storename ENDREQ
```

The server will reply with:

```
data
```

I will be using TCP for the transmission of data because it seems much more robust and easy to implement using the libraries that I am using.

I am not too knowledgeable when it comes to Java, especially with J2ME. How to implement the Java side?

CHANGE:
It is quite easy for me to implement a web server on the C++ side, so please feel free to use HTTP for the protocol!

Comment: Not an answer, so a comment. You’re working to hard. Use a simple HTTP server and JSON for read and write. Lots of support in all languages. The protocol sounds like it can even be REST-like.

Comment: Well, it ends up that the library I am using makes it easier to write a full HTTP server than a regular TCP server. Is there a way how I can send an HTTP request using Java ME, with POST?
This would make coding so much easier!

Comment: I would recommend [JSONRPC](http://www.jsonrpc.org/) instead, possibly on a TCP transport keeping the same connection.

Comment: **[Unclear what help you need](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important "see: 'Why is research important?'").** Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell what problem you are trying to solve or what aspect of your approach needs to be corrected or explained. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use HttpClient in Java ME.  It's just located under a different namespace (javax.microedition.io.HttpClient).  You can find some sample code in the official MID Profile documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/io/HttpConnection.html)

Comment: This is the method that I will use. However, now I am wondering about implementation! ;)

Answer (score -1):

Use an embedded http server - mongoose or civetweb or any of the others, they are trivially easy to implement (add a file to your build, set some options in an array, call a method to start it listening).

Then you can make http requests using java, see the ['SO tutorial'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

Comment: 'SO tutorial' you refer won't work for [Java ME](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-me/info) - for a start, there is no `java.net` package in Java ME (CLDC/MIDP)

Comment: @gnat are you sure about that? There are [plenty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098824/post-http-request-from-j2me) [of SO posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972400/getting-a-http-connection-in-j2me?rq=1) about making http calls from J2ME clients using `HttpConnection`, and [here's a tutorial](http://www.wirelessdevnet.com/channels/java/features/j2me_http.phtml) for using http in j2me. Apparently the "The HttpConnection class is guaranteed available on all MIDP devices."

Comment: I am 100% sure that there's no `java.net` package in CLDC/MIDP, their API is available online and you can check yourself. That makes particular tutorial you referred irrelevant, as it's heavily based on `java.net` API. As for using http, it's _conditionally_ available and it depends on specific device features. [GCF API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/index-155711.html) is relatively widespread because of CLDC popularity

Comment: I looked at the API link you gave, it does have [HttpConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/index.html) in there as part of the spec, "since MIDP 1.0". The API says there is a HttpConnection, and http is what he wants. I don't know what more I can say to help the OP except to point him to the spec's http API, tutorials and SO posts about this. Java.net seems to be the irrelevance here.

Comment: just take a look at that SO tutorial you refer in [the answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/254790/31260): "How to use **java.net.URLConnection** etc..." Now, re-check that MIDP API you looked at again, does it show **java.net** package? it doesn't and that's the point. Tutorial you recommend refers API which is irrelevant in the context of the question asked, that's my point